# Call PL/SQL stored procedure from shell script and capture the out outParameter

Tags: shell, plsql

Question:

I have a PL/SQL stored procedure callServlet(wire_type in varchar2, out_flag out varchar2). In this stored procedure I have to
call a servlet.
Initially I need to have a shell script which executes this callServlet stored proc by passing in , out parameters from shell.
I need to capture the out_flag9Out parameter) value from stored procedure and I have to evaluate the stored out_flag value
to determine the value of out_flagg is success or not_success.

**Can you kindly please let me know the below things**

1. How can I call the stored procedure (callServlet)from shell script by passing the in and out parameters?
2. How can I caputre the out parameter which sent by callServlet stored procedure?
3. How could I evaluate the out parameter of callServlet to know whether the status is success or not?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

First create an SQL*plus script called *callServlet.sql*:

```
var l_flag varchar2(100)

begin
  callServlet('&1', :l_flag);
end;
/

print l_flag
```

Then call the SQL*plus with the SQL script from a shell script using backticks:

```
flag=`sqlplus user/secret@database @callServlet.sql "xy"`
```

The out parameter will be assigned to the shell variable *flag*. *"xy"* is the value for the parameter wire_type.

Comment: I tried this and when I execute the shell script it is not ending simply its starting without any result .. I have to use (ctrl Z) to abrupt it on the console. And also  to use this we ahve a problem flag=`sqlplus user/secret@callServlet.sql "xy"` . We alreadyusing flag=`sqlplus user/secret@DATABASE_B to connect to particular database and so I have to usie this command in the following way flag=`sqlplus user/secret@DATABASE_B@callServlet.sql "xy"` , I do not thisnk this is going to work

Comment: I'm sorry but there was a mistake in the shell script. And you have precisely pointed me to the mistaken statement. I've fixed it now.